Should I use 24.04 LTS or 24.10?
Beginner here. So this might be a stupid question but I couldn't find an answer. I installed 24.10 on my Thinkpad T495 because it was the newest version. Later I found out that the 24.04 has long term support. Should I downgrade to that or does it even matter?
My goal is to learn linux and use my laptop as my daily driver for now. I'm definetly not a power user at least not yet, so I would like to have a stable and reliable system without any unnessesary hassle. However I have not run into any problems so far.
Is there some benefits to using the latest version over the lts one or is it mainly meant for developers and such? Also if I choose to, can I downgrade to 24.04 LTS without doing a clean install and starting all over again?

This question is similar to: How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Both 24.04 and 24.10 are stable releases, 24.10 has newer software, and will force you to learn about the release-upgrade process far earlier, as you'll have a number of jumps before you reach the next LTS at 26.04 and can [then] decide if you stay on the 6-9 month release-upgrade cycle OR stay for years on the LTS with a minimally but aging system. Pros & Cons with both approaches.

This question is similar to: What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you are in a production environment that requires stability or want to have fewer major upgrades, then you want the LTS version.
However, if you are up for a little experimentation and doing a major version upgrade every ~6 months until the next LTS, then staying with 24.10 is fine (until 25.04 comes out anyway, at which point you need to upgrade quickly).
Unless you hit a major bug in 24.10, it's less effort to stay on what you installed until 25.04 comes out, at which point you can decide if you want to upgrade immediately or downgrade to 24.04 and keep 24.04 until 26.04 comes out.

at which point you can decide if you want to upgrade immediately or downgrade to 24.04 and keep 24.04 until 26.04 comes out. Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular Oriole) is a non-LTS version released on October 10, 2024. It will go End Of Life (EOL) on July 10, 2025. If the system is not updated at that time you could risk security issues. Further, there is no downgrade path other than to re-install the earlier version.

Right... the only downgrade path is to reinstall.  So you can reinstall now.  Or you can wait until July 2025 and decide if you want to downgrade (reinstall) then or upgrade then.  Upgrading is somewhat easier, but you will have to do it 3x to get from 24.10 to 26.04.  And it's not just "less secure" if you don't upgrade...  you lose support and it becomes much more difficult to upgrade if you don't do it on time.  This is true for the LTS version too, but the window is 5 years instead of 5(?) months.

If one keeps /home on its own partition  )or disk), one can upgrade the system, choose a "Something else" install, point its /home at your /home, (and this is IMPORTANT) uncheck the "Format" box, and install the new release.
